# args attribute of an exception subclass's type changes from string to tuple

Tags: python

This happens on both python2.6 and python3:

```
class Error(Exception):
    def __init__(self, args):
            print(type(args))
            print(type(self.args)) # From BaseException
            self.args = args
            print(type(self.args))

Error("foo")
```

This results in:

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'tuple'>
<type 'tuple'>
Error('f', 'o', 'o')
```

For some reason, the args attribute is coerced into a tuple.
Might the fact that it's defined in C have something to do with it? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/exceptions.c

The name of the args argument is unrelated. Changing it to 'a' results in the same behavior, as long as it is assigned to self.args.

Comment: Why did this question suddenly get closed as a duplicate, 11 years after it was asked? The linked question is definitely related, but hardly a duplicate.

Comment: Additionally, this question predates the question it is supposedly a duplicate of by 5 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code you link to, there is a setter defined for the "args" attribute.  Look for BaseException_set_args - it is being set (elsewhere in the linked code) as the setter for args.  So when you write `self.args = args`, you're really calling the function BaseException_set_args, with `args` as the argument.

If you then look in BaseException_set_args, it is coercing the argument into a tuple.  If you give try to set self.args to something that can't be converted to a tuple (e.g. try `Error(23)`), you'll get a TypeError.